# Pyspark import dictionary from external file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use a dictionary in code to check my columns data-types.

```py
conversions = {
    "COL1": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL2": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c, dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL3": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c, dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL4": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("float"),
    "COL5": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL6": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
}

validateDF = inputDF.withColumn(
    "dataTypeValidations",
    f.concat_ws(
        ",",
        *[
            f.when(
                v(k).isNull() & f.col(k).isNotNull(), f.lit(k + " not valid")
            ).otherwise(f.lit("None"))
            for k, v in conversions.items()
        ]
    ),
)
```

The above code works fine if the dictionary is embedded within the same program. However, if I were to import it from a different file like

```
from dataTypeDictionary import conversions
```

this fails with the error

```
 f.concat_ws(",",
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'concat_ws'
```

How would I handle the externalized dictionary set?

Comment: What is the piece of code you have in `dataTypeDictionary` ?

Comment: ```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
conversions = {
    "COL1": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL2": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c,dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL3": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c,dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL4": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("float"),
    "COL5": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL6": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string")
}
```


sorry, the comment sections doesn't format code properly

Answer (score 0):

the error is `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'concat_ws'`.
If you look where you have this line, it is : `f.concat_ws`.

Which simply means that `f` is wrongly defined. It is not, as it should `pyspark.sql.functions`, but it is an object `TextIOWrapper`.

Are you doing somewhere `with open() as f` ? or something else ? You are overwritting on `f` somewhere in your code.

As a test, you can add `from pyspark.sql import functions as f` before `validateDF` definition.

And please, use an IDE. It can help track where you redefine objects.

Comment: No i am not, I am just importing the dictionary as 
from dataTypeDictionary import conversions

Comment: @Kashyapgv well, look at the error : `concat_ws` is not in `dataTypeDictionary` as you only import `conversions`. There is something in your code that you are hidding. We need [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you furthermore.

Comment: Well, i pasted snippets of the code, not the entire program here. I was importing functions in my main program as well.